# Customize React Antd table header with table data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

In my React project, I need to customize antd table header as follows 
[image]

I have added sample code bellow.

I need to have Sum of the amount in the header of the Amount column 
[image]

Sample Code:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/great-sun-534cd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use title function like this for get total of amount fields

```
const columns = [

    {
      title: () => { 
        var total = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          total += data[i].amount;
        }
        return <div>total {total}</div>;
      } ,
      dataIndex: "date",
      width: 200
    },
    {
      title: "Amount",
      dataIndex: "amount",
      width: 100
    }
  ];
```

Example link here https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-wiles-st6wl?fontsize=14